# Data from web Application not getting passed to ElasticSearch

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, logging, nlog

We have a .Net web application and we were already logging to csv file. We just started logging with Elastic search. I am able to see a log on Kibana but none of the information from application added to LogEventInfo is visible here though I can see that contentLength is changed based on length of information sent. I can only see http details in Kibana for each log. Can you let me know what could be the issue.

Configuration looks like

```
<target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">

  <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" uri="http://<url>:<portNumber>/">

    <field name ="MachineName" layout="${machinename}" layoutType="System.String" />

  </target>

</target>
```

Data like Machine Name is not shown on Kibana, I can see it in csv log created simultaneously.

nlog configuration. Rule in configuration section to write log

```
" <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="elk" enabled="true" />"
```

Data is logged using following code:

```
var theEvent= new LogEventInfo( logLevel,this.logger.Name,activityInfo.LogMessage // The message to log. ); 
theEvent.Properties[APPLICATION_NAME] = applicationName; 
theEvent.Properties[ACTIVITY_NAME] = activityInfo.ActivityName; 
this.logger.Log (theEvent); –
```

Comment: Configuration of what? How is the log data logged to ES?

Comment: nlog configuration. 
Rule in configuration section to write log 
" <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="elk" enabled="true" />"  
Data is logged using following code: 
var theEvent= new LogEventInfo( logLevel,this.logger.Name,activityInfo.LogMessage // The message to log.
       );
theEvent.Properties[APPLICATION_NAME] = applicationName;
theEvent.Properties[ACTIVITY_NAME] = activityInfo.ActivityName;  
this.logger.Log (theEvent);

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property IncludeAllProperties=true to your target.

Comment: It didn't work I tried.. I can't find logstash inside my project. Is it possible that logstash configuration is missing hence none of data from application is passed?